# How to get a readable string from binary data in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a string with a few non non-printable bytes. I want to convert this string into a human readable format. Non-printable charachters can be represented with something like ? or <07>, printable charachters should remain untouched.

Is there an easy way to do that in PHP?

Comment: Can you explain what is `non binary bytes`?

Comment: A byte is always binary... Please supply us with an example input and output... In the meantime, read up on `ord()`, `chr()`, `unpack()` and `bindec()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do something like this.

My choice would be:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]/',function($char) {
    // format as desired, for instance:
    return "{".dechex(ord($char[0]))."}";
},$string);
```

You can define "non-printable" how you want, the one I did there is basically "Everything before Space, but allow Tab, CR and LF".

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I had to replace the double quotes around the pattern to singel quotes. Furhter more the function takes an array not a single character. So I had to change it to `function($match) {return "{".dechex(ord($match[0]))."}";}` .

Comment: @BetaRide I've updated my answer with those edits - sorry for the confusion there :D

Comment: well this fixed a problem for me where I could NOT explode a string even if I could see the needle in there, I just returned "" instead . thank you so much